# Password decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I have to solve the follwing problem which doesn't allow me to change the `add()` function, i.e. it needs to work for all 'untouched' functions that are decorated by the `@password("my_pswd")`, **meaning I cannot change the add() function.** I am not familiar with passing such an argument to a function and transfer it to the decorator. As for how i tried solving this issue, the decorator (which is the only thing I may change) is included in the original question.

Decorator:

> Write a parameterized decorator named "password" that takes a password as a parameter.
> The decorated function should take this password as a parameter and return its result. If the password is not provided, it should raise a ValueError exception. **The decorator should work with any function regardless of its named and positional parameters.**

Example:

```py
@password("secret")
def add(a, b):   #constant function, DO NOT MODIFY
    return a+b
    
add("h", 1, 2)   #ValueError
add(1, 2)            #ValueError
add("secret", 1, 2)    #3

def password(pswd):
    #code here
```

I've tried using a named decorator like this :

```py
def password(pswd):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if not f(*args) is pswd:
                raise ValueError("Invalid password")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

But, I get

```
line 28, in <module>
    add("h", 1, 2)
  File "//", line 16, in wrapper 
    if not f(*args) is pswd:
TypeError: add() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Any idea how to solve this? To be clear, **I can't modify the add function**, meaning I cannot give it a third positional argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrapper function should just check if the first argument is the password. And when the wrapper calls the original function it has to leave out the password argument. So the function signature should be

```
def wrapper(password_given, *args, **kwargs):
```

This allows it to pass only `*args` to the original function, which leaves out the first argument.

Then it should use `if pswd != pass:` to check the password -- you shouldn't use `is` to compare strings.

```
def password(pswd):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(password_given, *args, **kwargs):
            if password_given != pswd:
                raise ValueError("Invalid password")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: Could you say smt about security? The title could be misunderstood, it seems that's a safe method but you can get it `f = password("1234")(lambda: _)
true_psw = f.__closure__[1].cell_contents
print(true_psw)`

Comment: Since you can just look at the source code, there's clearly no security here. I think it's just a toy demonstration of what you can do with decorators.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked around and this is the conclusion I get :

The issue we're encountering is due to the fact that we're calling the add() function inside the decorator's wrapper with all the arguments passed to it, including the password. However, the add() function does not expect the password as an argument, which results in the "TypeError: add() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" error. To solve this problem while not modifying the add() function, we can modify the decorator's wrapper to accept the password as a separate argument.

```
def password(pswd):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(pswd_arg, *args, **kwargs):
            if pswd_arg != pswd:
                raise ValueError("Invalid password")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```